# Are all Summoning animals Immortal in a sense

Tags: naruto, boruto

The great toad sage was very young during the time of the sage of six paths (think about that for a second) and yet he is still alive, If I were to calculate his age, it would probably be a couple hundred eons.

The same thing goes for the great snake sage, who is also known to be quite old and is still a thing in the Boruto-verse.
Does this mean all Summoning animals can live for eternity if they don't die in battle? Or is it just a feat that can be achieved with sage mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The summoned animals live for a long period of time with respect to the human world, but that amount of lifespan is usual in their world (like toads in [Mount Myoboku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_My%C5%8Dboku)).

> Mount Myōboku has records of its population in a list, and the name of a Mount Myōboku toad stays there until it dies.[7]

I found the above in the wiki page of Mount Myoboku. So its safe to assume that toads do die and are not immortal. They just live very long.